# Passport.js local login with body validation and error handling

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I need body validation and better error handling without the first validation middleware. The code works very well, but I would like to delete the first middleware and manage validation within the second.

**routes/auth.js**

```
router.post('/signin', function(req, res, next){

    req.checkBody('email', 'Email is required.').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email', 'Invalid email format.').isEmail();
    req.checkBody('password', 'Password is required.').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password', 'The password length must be between 8 and 100.').isLength({min: 8, max: 100});

    var err = req.validationErrors();
    if (err) {
        res.status(400).send({ success: false, error: err});
        return;
    }
    next();
});

router.post('/signin', passport.authenticate('local', { session: false }), function(req, res){
    var user = req.user;
    return res.json({success: true, user: user});
});
```

As regards the error handling, if a user doesn't match, the error is:

```
{
  "error": "Invalid email and/or password"
}
```

and I would like this:

```
{
  "success":false,
  "error": "Invalid email and/or password"
}
```

How can I do it?

**passport.js**

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'password'
    },
    function(email, password, done) {
        User.findOne({ email: email, password: password },'-password', function (err, user) {
            if (err)return done(err);
            if(!user){
                var err = new Error('Invalid email and/or password');
                err.status = 401;
                return done(err, false);
            }

            return done(null, user);
        })
    }
));
```

Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want the validation to occur in the verification function of the `LocalStrategy` object.

Before you can do this, you first need access to the `req` object. For that, you need to enable the [`passReqToCallback`](http://passportjs.org/docs#association-in-verify-callback) option of the strategy:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField     : 'email',
        passwordField     : 'password',
        passReqToCallback : true
    },
    function(req, email, password, done) { ... });
```

From there, you can use the same validation code as in the first middleware:

```
function(req, email, password, done) {
    req.checkBody('email', 'Email is required.').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email', 'Invalid email format.').isEmail();
    req.checkBody('password', 'Password is required.').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password', 'The password length must be between 8 and 100.').isLength({min: 8, max: 100});

    var err = req.validationErrors();
    if (err) {
      return done(err, false, { success: false, error: err});
    }
    User.findOne({...});
});
```

And lastly, you need to use a custom callback for `passport.authenticate()` to handle the verification outcome:

```
router.post('/signin', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', { session : false }, function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    if (! user) {
      return res.status(400).json(info);
    }
    return res.json({ success : true, user : req.user});
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

The `info` argument to the callback maps to the third argument of the `done()` callback in the verification handler.

One thing to note is that Passport will not call the local strategy handler if `email` or `password` in the request body is empty, which makes the `notEmpty` validations moot.